# simulate user clicking udate button in a gridview with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, custom-controls

I have a custom web control *.ascx file. I am trying to simulate the user clicking the update button in a gridview using a java script. I have this script at the top of my .ascx page :

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">

        $(document).keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                document.getElementById("LinkButton1").click();
            }
        });

    </script>
```

The "LinkButton1" is located in this template field:

```
  <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" onKeyPress="" UseSubmitBehavior="True" CausesValidation="True" 
                              CommandName="Update" TabIndex="13" Text="Update"  ></asp:LinkButton>
                          &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                              CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
                      <ItemTemplate>
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That won't work because the click only works for attached events not for an anchor which is what a linkbutton is rendered as.

You can use this ..

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
    simulate(document.getElementById("LinkButton1"), "click");

        }
    });
```

function simulate(element, eventName) {
    var options = extend(defaultOptions, arguments[2] || {});
    var oEvent, eventType = null;

```
for (var name in eventMatchers) {
    if (eventMatchers[name].test(eventName)) { eventType = name; break; }
}

if (!eventType)
    throw new SyntaxError('Only HTMLEvents and MouseEvents interfaces are supported');

if (document.createEvent) {
    oEvent = document.createEvent(eventType);
    if (eventType == 'HTMLEvents') {
        oEvent.initEvent(eventName, options.bubbles, options.cancelable);
    }
    else {
        oEvent.initMouseEvent(eventName, options.bubbles, options.cancelable, document.defaultView,
          options.button, options.pointerX, options.pointerY, options.pointerX, options.pointerY,
          options.ctrlKey, options.altKey, options.shiftKey, options.metaKey, options.button, element);
    }
    element.dispatchEvent(oEvent);
}
else {
    options.clientX = options.pointerX;
    options.clientY = options.pointerY;
    var evt = document.createEventObject();
    oEvent = extend(evt, options);
    element.fireEvent('on' + eventName, oEvent);
}
return element;
```

}

function extend(destination, source) {
    for (var property in source)
        destination[property] = source[property];
    return destination;
}

var eventMatchers = {
    'HTMLEvents': /^(?:load|unload|abort|error|select|change|submit|reset|focus|blur|resize|scroll)$/,
    'MouseEvents': /^(?:click|dblclick|mouse(?:down|up|over|move|out))$/
};

var defaultOptions = {
    pointerX: 0,
    pointerY: 0,
    button: 0,
    ctrlKey: false,
    altKey: false,
    shiftKey: false,
    metaKey: false,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
};

Comment: editor messed up the formatting obviously.
BTW you are rendering static ID's in the control right?

Comment: Yes the ID's are static. I just used the designer to create the grid with no C# code behind.

Comment: This is a custom web control not it's own page. Could this have something to do with it?

Comment: it could where are you putting the javascript?
And have the page render and view source and post that.
Put alerts in the javascript and see if they are hit etc..

Comment: I have no control over the page that the control is rendered in. Is there a way to isolate this script to the div that it is in? For example <head> script1 </head> <body> script2 <div> script3 </div> </body>. I am almost positive this is why this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
document.getElementById('<%# ((GridViewRow)Container).FindControl("LinkButton2").ClientID %>').click();
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. "GridViewRow" should that be the Id of the gridview?

Comment: you call your function on your control linkbutton it's not id, it's type, link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow%28v=vs.80%29.aspx